# Get last 12 months based on the most recent dates in the file and not current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

How to get last 12 months based on the most recent dates in the file and not current date.

Most recent date in the file is `[Add_Datetime] = 2021-05-07`.

Thank you

This the query that I tried to run but there's no result because this query only take in consideration the current date.

```
SELECT 
    [Contact_Id],
    ([Add_Datetime]),
    [Arena_Name],
    [Event_Date],
    [Event_Name],
    [Season_Name],
    [Seat_Num],
    [Num_Seats],
    [Paid_value]
FROM 
    [Group CH].[dbo].[CustomerData]
WHERE
    [Add_Datetime] >= DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to compare the date to the latest date in the table, less 12 months:

```
where Add_Datetime > (
  select top(1) dateadd(month, -12, Add_Datetime)
  from [Group CH].dbo.CustomerData
  order by Add_Datetime desc
);
```